# How avoid Console to load webview2

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2022, webview2

I'm developing a NET CORE 6 console app with neither internet connections nor internet viewers and so forth.

When I run my code I see (in Task Manager) a LOT of Microsoft.Edge.Webview2 being loaded and, pretty worst, they remains active after my application ends and even after unload VS-2022.

I don't know why it is happening since my app just open and close local files - nothing more than this.

How can I avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: If you haven't include the `WebView2` package from Github, then it's NOT your program that does it.

Comment: Hi @PoulBak, tks for your answer. When I load VS2022, Webview2 does not appear, only when I run the program (many instances!) and they persist. And no, I'm not using nothing related to webview2. This is driving me crazy.